# Grails testing: New instance resolved to null if followed by .validate()

Tags: validation, testing, grails, nullpointerexception, constraints

I've got this domain class `Ward`. It's got this constraint `name` that I'd like to test
(`medi_abs` is the package `Ward` is located in):

```
package medi_abs

class Ward {

    String name
    static constraints = {
        name blank:false
    }
}
```

For now, the WardTests.groovy looks like the following:

```
package medi_abs

@TestFor(Ward)
@Mock(Ward)

class WardTests {
    void testInstance() {
        def wardx = new Ward(name: 'OP')
        assertEquals 'OP', wardx.name
    }
    void testConstraints() {
        mockForConstraintsTests(Ward)
        def wardx = new Ward(name: 'OP')
        assertTrue wardx.validate()
    }
}
```

When I run the `test-app Ward` command, testInstance will not fail, but testConstraints will, followed by this error message:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: validate for class: medi_abs.WardTests at medi_abs.WardTests.testConstraints
```

[ EDIT: Now the error message I get is this, can't tell why it changed: ]

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at grails.test.MockUtils$_addValidateMethod_closure87.doCall(MockUtils.groovy:1022)
at grails.test.MockUtils$_addValidateMethod_closure88.doCall(MockUtils.groovy:1065) 
at medi_abs.WardTests.testConstraints(WardTests.groovy:43)
```

It seems that in the first method, `Ward` is instantiated properly, but in connection with the validate() command, `wardx` is null. I could not find any good examples so far, am I using validate() wrong? Or is there even a better way to test constraints in Grails?

Comment: Have you tried adding [`@DomainClassUnitTestMixin`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/test/mixin/domain/DomainClassUnitTestMixin.html) as well?

Comment: I tried adding that, it worked for two test runs, then the errors came back.

Comment: Move `mockForConstraintsTests(Ward)` to `setup()` and see.

Comment: Again, a single time it said "All Tests Passed", then the errors were back. My full WardsTests.groovy now looks like [this](http://www.pasteall.org/45665/groovy), the three middle test methods all throw the exception as described above. The number attribute has a uniqueness constraint.

Comment: Apologize for misguiding while preoccupied with something else, Sergio has the answer you need.

Answer (score 5):

If you use `@TestFor` annotation, there's no need to add `@Mock` for your domain class. You need the `@Mock` only for associations, or when you're running a unit test for other artefact (controllers, for example).

And the mock method assignature is `void mockForConstraintsTests(Class clazz, List instances = [])`, so you need to pass the list of instances that will be prepared.

So your code should look like:

```
package medi_abs

@TestFor(Ward)
class WardTests {
    void testInstance() {
        def wardx = new Ward(name: 'OP')
        assertEquals 'OP', wardx.name
    }
    void testConstraints() {
        def wardx = new Ward(name: 'OP')
        mockForConstraintsTests(Ward, [wardx])
        assertTrue wardx.validate()
    }
}
```

Comment: @dmahapatro Don't worry :-)

Comment: For whatever reason, the error messages again returned after one or two test runs.

Comment: Tried to run the test one more time this morning, first no errors, then errors again after two test runs - right now I'm back to no errors. I'm starting to believe that it's not really a grails problem.